# lxd availability on CentOS

Tags: juju, lxc, lxd

I want to implement lxd and juju on CentOS (or Redhat). I have found the matrix https://www.flockport.com/lxc-and-lxd-support-across-distributions/, in which it is clearly stated, that LXD is not available (yet) on CentOS. Questions:

- The matrix is of 2015, are there any improvements there (i.e. is LXD available yet on CentOS) ?
- How can I use juju without LXD (so pure LXC's, that is, when LXD is not available yet) ?

Comment: I don't see this as an Ubuntu-specific question. Could you clarify if i am wrong or not? General unix/linux questions are better fitted in http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @dufte This question is on topic.

Comment: Questions about services provided by Canonical is on-topic here, So I think this is on-topic on Ask Ubuntu. See [here](http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

> The matrix is of 2015, are there any improvements there (i.e. is LXD available yet on CentOS) ?

You can find in https://copr.fedorainfracloud.org/coprs/ganto/lxd/ a COPR repo  with LXD for Fedora 25/26. You will disable SELinux for work.

Now for CentOS 7, you can research https://gist.github.com/AdamIsrael/e6b4a540233a7be6d28decd917b60c3d to check LXD and Juju for CentOS 7. can be a little hackish way, but some people get working this.

> How can I use juju without LXD (so pure LXC's, that is, when LXD is not available yet) ?

You can deploy with Juju in Amazon Web Services, Google Compute Engine, and Microsoft Azure. I imagine that you refer to LXC instead of LXD for local deployment for tests. The old Juju 1.25 version will support this (https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.25/config-LXC) but for Juju 2.x versions, the local deployment is supported only with LXD.